# Windows 10 Mobile: Accessing device log (like logcat on Android)

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to find a way to view the device log of a Windows 10 Mobile Device.

I have already searched my way through various forums but it seems to be very new topic not many have come across so far.

So my **question is**:

How do I do this?

I'm looking for something vaguely equivalent to **Android Studio's Logcat**.

I know my way around in Visual Studio, I hoped there would be some way to do it via the debug console, but as far as I know that thing is limited to the current app you are developing.

Any help would be nice. I'm kind of lost here.

Cheers.

Comment: There is no device log that you can look at.  Just wondering what you need to see it?

Comment: I need to look at the debug output of some apps I didn't write myself. So I don't have the sourcecode and can debug them directly in VisualStudio. But I know of a library that is built into some apps, that writes to the debug output. And I need to see that output. Might I ask what the source for your statement is?

Comment: Sorry cant find a link that shows anything about a device log for windows 10 mobile.  I would use something like hockey app to write the debug data to so you can see it online

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will try that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no equivalent of Logcat.
But I can advise you some alternatives:

1) Visual Studio Console: you can display information from the code directly on the Visual Studio console. To do it just add below line to the fragment of your code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is information to be displayed on the VS Console...");
```

You can also change the color of the font:
a. For example for errors you can set it to be RED:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

2. If you need some more complex solution you can try Microsoft HockeyApp.
   With this tool you can measure performance of your app. Not only bugs but also how many users use your app (they can even contact you to report errors).

https://www.hockeyapp.net/features/

3. Third solutuion here is to use this official Logging APIs samples avilable on GitHub:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Logging

Hope this wil help you.